# Input Modal using Bulma cant parsing id Laravel

Tags: laravel

So iam using bulma for my modal input and i have problem in my input always get 404 . and this problem is this id cant stored on this form . you can see this form like this and i dont know where my fault

1.Table // #update , this problem on here this {{i->id}} cant send into js code , whats wrong ??

```
  @foreach ($data as $i)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $i->turunan_anak->uraian}}</td>
       <td>16</td>
       <td>46</td>
       <td>{{$i->kode_rekening}}</td>
       <td>{{$i->uraian}}</td>
       @if(empty($i->user_id))
       <td>belum dipilih</td>
       @else()
       <td>   $i->users->nama_unit</td>
        @endif
       
       <td> 
        <a class = "button is-danger modal-button" id="lanuchModal"
                  data-id="{{$i->id}}"
                  data-user_id="{{$i->user_id}}"
                  data-target="#modal"
                  >Pilih Pelaksana</a> 
       </td> 
       @endforeach
```

2.Modal

```
         <form  action="{{route('store_id'),'test'}} " method="post">
                  @csrf
                  {{method_field('patch')}}
                <div id="modal" class="modal">
                  <div class="modal-background"></div>
                  <div class="modal-card">
                    <header class="modal-card-head">
                      <p class="modal-card-title">Pilih Pelaksana</p>
                      <button class="delete" id="modal-close" aria-label="close"></button>
                    </header>
                    <section class="modal-card-body">
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">                      
                          
                              <div class="select is-medium is-danger"> 
                                <select id="user_id" name="user_id">
                                  @foreach($pelaksana as $id => $nama )
                                  <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $nama }}</option>
                                  @endforeach
                                </select>
                              </div>
                              <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </section>
                    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
                      <button type="submit" class="button is-success">Save changes</button>
                    </footer>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

3. My Js for modal  # this id not received data-id , and its the problem

   ```
    <script>
    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var id           = button.data('id')
        var user_id      = button.data('user_id')
        var modal = $(this)

        modal.find('.modal-card-body #id').val(id);
        modal.find('.modal-card-body #user_id').val(user_id);
    })
     </script>
   ```
4. and last its my die dump

> ```
> array:4 [▼
>   "_token" => "KV5anuTdRXWt3RKHtFMzgud6DN69PzXQX0Pj9ire"
>   "_method" => "patch"
>   "user_id" => "3"
>   "id" => null
> ]
> ```

this id always null i dont know what happen , anyone have solution ?

#update my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $pelaksana = User::where('roles_id' ,2)->pluck('nama_unit', 'id'); 
    $data = TurunanBelanja::all();
    // dd($pelaksana);
   return view('admin.dashboard',['data'=>$data , 'pelaksana' => $pelaksana]);
}

public function store_id(Request $request)
{
    $data = TurunanBelanja::findOrFail($request->id);
    $data->user_id =  $request->user_id;
    $data->update();
    
    return back()->with('success', 'Sukses Update Data');
    
}
```

this controller is work normaaly , i try to set value id=1 . and this input is work normmaly

Comment: Could you share laravel code?

Comment: u mean controller ?

Comment: yes  please share your controller code

Comment: this controller dont have a problem , i try to set id = 1 , and this input is work normally . but on automatiicly input , its doesnt work